Gitlab artifact not copying with git depth=0
I am trying to implement secret scanning within my Gitlab CI environment, I have created a custom gitleaks image which has a python script to send the findings to securityhub where they can be tracked in the long run, now the issue is when I am adding variable GIT_DEPTH=0 for scanning all commits in the repository
  stage: secret
  image: gitleaks-custom-image
  before_script: []
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 0
  script:
    - gitleaks detect --report-format json --report-path $CI_PROJECT_DIR/gitleaks_report.json
    - cp /usr/bin/send_securityhub.py $CI_PROJECT_DIR/send_securityhub.py
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/send_securityhub.py
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/gitleaks_report.json
    when: always
  allow_failure: true

secret_send:
  stage: secret
  needs: [secret_scan]
  script:
    - pip3 install boto3
    - chmod +x send_securityhub.py
    - python3 send_securityhub.py gitleaks_report.json

I get the following error
WARNING: send_securityhub.py: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory that too only for the send_securityhub.py file and when I remove GIT_DEPTH=0 variable it is able to pick up the python file
